# How to group and order list of lists based on certain flags in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I was working on an automation problem where I end up with a list of lists which look something like this:

```
in_list=[ ['data_1_1', 'id_1', True, False, False, False, 'data_1_5'],
          ['data_2_1', 'id_1', False, True, False, False, 'data_2_5'],
          ['data_3_1', 'id_2', True, False, False, False, 'data_3_5'],
          ['data_4_1', 'id_1', True, False, False, False, 'data_4_5'],
          ['data_5_1', 'id_1', False, True, False, False, 'data_5_5'],
          ['data_6_1', 'id_2', True, False, False, False, 'data_6_5'] ]
```

I wanted to group the lists based on the id(2nd element in each list) and order it based on the flags (3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th element of the list),

Expected output:

```
out_list=[ ['data_1_1', 'id_1', True, False, False, False, 'data_1_5'],
           ['data_4_1', 'id_1', True, False, False, False, 'data_4_5'],
           ['data_2_1', 'id_1', False, True, False, False, 'data_2_5'],
           ['data_5_1', 'id_1', False, True, False, False, 'data_5_5'],
           ['data_3_1', 'id_2', True, False, False, False, 'data_3_5'],
           ['data_6_1', 'id_2', True, False, False, False, 'data_6_5'] ]
```

Explanation:
`out_list` is grouped in the same order w.r.t id and further ordered based on the True/False flags, (simply put, the lists which have the same set of flags and the same id come together)

So far, I am iterating over the entire list of lists and checking element by element which is neither pythonic nor scalable. Is there a faster/better way to do it?

Comment: Your expected output isn't grouping anything, just sorting.

Comment: Does `sorted(in_list, key=lambda x: (x[1], -x[2], -x[3], -x[4], -x[5]))` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output isn't grouping anything, just sorting the elements in the outer list.

Since you want to order by the ID and then by the flags, use a slice of the inner list that contains these elements as your sort key

```
in_list=[ ['data_1_1', 'id_1', True, False, False, False, 'data_1_5'],
          ['data_2_1', 'id_1', False, True, False, False, 'data_2_5'],
          ['data_3_1', 'id_2', True, False, False, False, 'data_3_5'],
          ['data_4_1', 'id_1', True, False, False, False, 'data_4_5'],
          ['data_5_1', 'id_1', False, True, False, False, 'data_5_5'],
          ['data_6_1', 'id_2', True, False, False, False, 'data_6_5'] ]

sorted(in_list, key=lambda x: x[1:6])
```

Which gives this:

```
[['data_2_1', 'id_1', False, True, False, False, 'data_2_5'],
 ['data_5_1', 'id_1', False, True, False, False, 'data_5_5'],
 ['data_1_1', 'id_1', True, False, False, False, 'data_1_5'],
 ['data_4_1', 'id_1', True, False, False, False, 'data_4_5'],
 ['data_3_1', 'id_2', True, False, False, False, 'data_3_5'],
 ['data_6_1', 'id_2', True, False, False, False, 'data_6_5']]
```

If you want to sort the `True` flags first, you'll have to negate them in the `key` function.

```
>>> sorted(in_list, key=lambda x: [x[1]] + [not f for f in x[2:6]])

[['data_1_1', 'id_1', True, False, False, False, 'data_1_5'],
 ['data_4_1', 'id_1', True, False, False, False, 'data_4_5'],
 ['data_2_1', 'id_1', False, True, False, False, 'data_2_5'],
 ['data_5_1', 'id_1', False, True, False, False, 'data_5_5'],
 ['data_3_1', 'id_2', True, False, False, False, 'data_3_5'],
 ['data_6_1', 'id_2', True, False, False, False, 'data_6_5']]
```